# Cloud Automation Manager on IBM Cloud Private - deployement not available and pods pending

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-automation-manager

I installed the Helm Release of CAM on the catalog, however, the individual components of CAM are not being deployed. There doesn't seem to be any deployement available and all the pods are pending of CAM.

[Screenshot of Deployments of CAM on ICP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU1WM.png)

With NFS installed, once I deploy CAM from the catalog, the PVs are now bounded to the PV claims from the start. However, the same problem persists, there are no available deployments for CAM and the pods are stuck at either init:0/1, pending, or ContainerCreating without any change.

Edit:
When I checked the pods, the pending error was due to insufficient memory, so I added another worker node and I no longer have any pending deployments. However I still do have the issue with pods being stuck at init(0/1), ContainerCreating and ImagePullBackoff.
Here are some of the errors: [Init(0/1) Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhMvy.png) [ImagePullBackoff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5wYt.png) [ContainerCreating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPXjP.png)

Answer (score 1):

could be a handful of issues, depending on how many try/retry of the CAM deploy you have attempted:
- delete the PVCs
- edit the PVs to remove any PV claim (or delete the PV and recreate it)
- ensure the NFS exports are defined correctly:  (See bottom of page)
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37_3.1.0.0/cam_create_pv.html
- remove any prior files/data from the PV locations on disk
- delete the failed CAM chart deploy if still there

If you're facing more trouble, suggest to open a support case so we can help you right away!
ibm.biz/icpsupport

thx.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may related to the CAM PVs not created or not bonded. Could you please check 4 CAM PVs created before deploy CAM

From ICP console > Platform > Storage , you should see 4 CAM PVs as follows:

[image]

Please check https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37_3.1.0.0/cam_create_pv.html regarding how to create CAM PVs

Comment: Requests for clarification or further information should go in a comment, not an answer. Additionally, please don't rely on links for the bulk of the information in your answer. Links can go dead, or the information on the other end can be changed.

Comment: Hello Jeffrey, Thanks for the response! I already followed those instructions to create the PVs before I deployed CAM, however, the PVs are status is still released, and the PV claim status is still on pending.

Comment: Do you have the NFS client installed on all of your icp cluster node.

Comment: e.g.  if your icp cluster running on Ubuntu OS, ensure the following NFS client package installed on all the nodes:

Comment: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nfs-common .

Comment: From your ICP master node,  ensure it is able to mount to the NFS shared driver,   e.g.  mount -o <NFS server IP>:/export/CAM_db /mnt/testdb

Comment: I've installed the NFS package, but the PVs weren't bounded. I kept the PV claims and deleted the PVs themselves, and when I added the PVs again, the the PVs became bounded.

Comment: However, none of the deployments are still available and the pods are still pending. Was that the wrong way to get the PVs bounded?

Comment: Hello Jeffrey, I deleted cam, the PVs and the PV claims and started fresh. With NFS installed, once I deploy CAM from the catalog, the PVs are now bounded to the PV claims from the start. However, the same problem persists, there are no available deployments for CAM and the pods are stuck at either init:0/1, pending, or ContainerCreating without any change.

Comment: from your icp master VM run the following cmd to see why pods are in pending state:   1) kubectl get -n services pods   2) kubectl describe -n services pods <pod-name> .

Comment: Hello Jeffrey, Thanks for the response. The Pending issues were due to insufficient memory, so I no longer have that issue. However, I still get stuck during Initialization or Creating Containers. I added the images of the errors to the main post.

Answer (score -1):

Please review the options for offline installation of IBM Cloud Automation Manager. With an offline installation, it can take hours until the pod cam-iaas is running.

https://developer.ibm.com/cloudautomation/2018/10/18/ibm-cloud-automation-manager-3-1-delivers-improved-offline-installation-experience/